# jdi light framework for JSF Primefaces selectone component

Tags: jdiframework

I have page for country selection as list box of SelectOneMenu of primefaces component. This page has other list items of same time.

Used the dropdown with JDropdown

```
@JDropdown(root = ".ui-selectonemenu", expand = ".ui-selectonemenu-trigger", list = "option",
 value = ".ui-selectonemenu-label")
 Dropdown country;

// 
county.select("Canada");
```

when executed it finds more than one and unable to select

Question - I don't see and id for the JDropdown annotation, so how do we get this working?

Appreciated your help.